# What's the purpose of Android allowing reading folder trees without storage permission?

Tags: android, android-permissions

You can read/enter folders without storage permission. But can't see any files. Is this intentional?

Comment: That will depend a lot on the specific folder and the specific files.

Comment: @CommonsWare Mainly mean /storage/0/emulated.